# React - variable / scope issue

Tags: reactjs, events, scope

I am trying to create a React component that onMount, fetches a list of books and then subscribes to a hub that notifies React of any changes to the data set via Server Sent Events.

I am having issues with the following code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const BookList = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  const getBooks = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://localhost:8443/books.jsonld');
    const data = await response.json();
    setBooks(data['hydra:member']);

    ...
    const hub = new URL(hubUrl[1]);
    ...
    const eventSource = new EventSource(hub);
    eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
      updateBookList(JSON.parse(event.data));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getBooks();
  }, []);

  const updateBookList = () => {
    console.log(books);
  };

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
      {books.map((book) => (
        <tr key={book['@id']}>
          <td onClick={updateBookList}>{book.name}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
};
export default BookList;
```

When I load the page `books` is set to `[]`
It then fetches data from the api and sets `books = [ {}, {}, {}...]`

If I click on a book name it calls `updateBookList` and I get `[ {}, {}, {}...]` in the console.

At this point, if I trigger an `eventSource.onmessage` It calls `updateBookList` and i get `[]` in the console. It should be returning a populated array but it is not.

It appears that rather than using the current value of `books`, it is using `books` initial value.

Comment: State updates are asynchronous, what you get `console.log()`'ed inside `updateBookList()` is not necessarily what you have in your state. Use React extension for DevTools instead to keep track of component's state.

Comment: The state should be updated at this point to include the books. I can see all of the books on the page, and when I click a book it is logging all of the books. I feel like the onmessage function is storing the value of the state before its populated. Then when its fired it uses this stored value rather than the actual state value. I could be completely off here.

Comment: I have updated the question to simplify the code and remove any confusion

Comment: As @Ahmad answered the problem is that you add the `onmessage` handler inside a `useEffect` which never re-runs. So, the version of `updateBookList` and sub-sequently `books` will be the one created on the first render and will always point to the initial value of `books`. (*I would suggest your revert your question to its original code as it illustrates the real problem, while the simplified code does not exhibit the problem*)

Comment: You're not using state. You should store books in state.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I agree the update has led to more confusion. I have reverted the post. If useEffect is the issue, what would be the proper way to implement this?

Comment: @Ahmad you were right it had to do with useEffect. I was confused at how this worked. If you repost your answer I will mark as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused at how useEffect works.
Here is the solution I found:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const BookList = (props) => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  const [eventSource, setEventSource] = useState();

  const getBooks = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(props.url);
    const fetchData = await response.json();

    props.setData(fetchData['hydra:member']);

    ...
    const hub = new URL(hubUrl[1]);
    ...
    setEventSource(new EventSource(hub));
  };

  const updateBookList = () => {
    console.log(books);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  useEffect( () => {
    if(eventSource) {
      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        updateBookList(JSON.parse(event.data));
      };
      return () => {
        eventSource.close();
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
      {books.map((book) => (
        <tr key={book['@id']}>
          <td onClick={updateBookList}>{book.name}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
};
export default DataSource;
```